# zk listbox visible if model size greater than zero

Tags: java, zk

I want to hide my listbox if model is empty.

```
 <listbox  visible="@load(vm.list.size gt 0)" model="@load(vm.list)">...</listbox>
```

I got an error

> For input string: "size" at [file:/D:/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp4/wtpwebapps/kApp/request/Approval.zul, line:162]

I think this error, because ZK ListModelList doesn't have property getSize, it has only function size, that return the size of its.

Comment: What is the type of `vm.list`? Do you have a longer stacktrace? Which ZK Version?

Comment: zk 7.0. I use MVVM, list is type of ListModelList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `()`-brackets to call the function directly:

```
<listbox  visible="@load(vm.list.size() gt 0)" model="@load(vm.list)">...</listbox>
```

Here is a working [fiddle example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3qd0j8e/3-SO33249881).